# Spring-Data Jpa Inheritance: Keeping Entity Id's in Children Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm dealing with a couple of Entities with Tree like structures that were getting more complicated so I decided to create an abstract class for it so code was a bit more mainainable:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class TreeStructure<T extends TreeStructure>
{
    @ManyToOne
    protected  T parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected Set<T> children = new HashSet<>();
    //...
```

Then I have two Entities which extend it:

```
@Entity(name = "TreeStructureOne")
public class TreeStructureOne extends TreeStructure<TreeStructureOne>
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonProperty("TreeStructureOne_id")
    private long id;
```

And I basically want the database to be completely unaware of this `TreeStructure` abstraction and save all of the fields in each Entities tableand expected `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` to deal with that. But it seems I need to define the `Id` in the `TreeStructure` Entity at least or I get:

`Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: TreeStructure`

And I don't want to add an `ID` into the abstract class since this makes three tables in the database called: `HT_TREE_STRUCTURE`, `HT_TREE_STRUCTURE_ONE` and `HT_TREE_STRUCTURE_TWO` with one field `ID` each one.

Is there any solution to that?

Comment: Did you try to use `@MappedSuperclass` for the class `TreeStructure` instead of `@Entity` and `@Inheritance`? `@MappedSuperclass` does not have its  own Table and is not an Entity. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html

Comment: Nope, I didn't know about it! It passed all the tests I made so exactly what I was looking for. Much thanks!

Comment: Great! I just formulated this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `TreeStructure` is not an `@Entity` use only `@MappedSuperclass`

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class TreeStructure<T extends TreeStructure> {
```

instead of `@Entity` and `@Inheritance` for the parent class.

You can find `@MappedSuperclass` in the [Oracle JEE API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html).